# what is the best way for convert VisualFoxPro Database To Sql Server 2008 - Without Damage in Unicode Data?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, foxpro

what is the best way for convert VisualFoxPro Database To Sql Server 2008 - Without Damage in Unicode Data ?

thanks in advance

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect the [SQL Server Upsizing Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0y0ee377%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to give you the best shot, but maybe I'm being unreasonably optimistic today.

Should that fail, you'll want to

- Set up your target database with a
  [compatible collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508.aspx).
- Don't let your data rest in the
  filesystem before arriving at its
  destination.
- If the data must rest in the
  filesystem, make sure all your tools
  support your variant of Unicode, and
  that your [codepages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are
  compatible.
- Expect things to almost work. (That's
  a Bad Thing, but it seems to be the
  rule with Unicode.) Prove your system and processes with fiendish
  tests beforehand.